# Django sessions instead of user model

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to use sessions in django instead of a user model?
I know django creates sessions for each "new" client accessing the server. I want to be able to store attributes like I would on a user model and be able to retrieve a session based on a form. *more like logging in an existing session on a "new" client*.

Whats the most elegant approach? I'm thinking of implementing a middleware

Comment: Django's `request.user` works with sessions. It links the logged in user to the `session_id`. The sessions are provided by the sessionmiddleware. But it is not clear to me what you aim to achieve.

Comment: Django creates sessions for anonymous users too. My aim is to authenticate using session, no users. A new client can retrieve all attributes attached any session by supply a session id.

Comment: it creates session for anonymous users, in fact for every session a different session (so not one for all anonymous users) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/ . But with the session middleware you can alter the session data. So I do not see what you try to ask.

Comment: I want to be able to change the session attached to a client.

Comment: well the documentation regarding the session explain how to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/